# Google App Script to Copy Specific Cells to a Google Document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

How can I copy cells from a Google Sheet? Like Different cell

A32 - Header in Google Doc
B33 - Subject
B34 - Body 1
B35 - Body 2

So that in Google Document, it would look like an email content.

I tried creating in code but it seems its near but I don't know how to add a new line and put headings and don't change the text styles.

```
 function copyTest() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

      // create a new document and add student as editor
      var newDoc = DocumentApp.create("Copy: " + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName());
      var targetDoc = newDoc.getId();

      var header = ss.getRange('A32').getValues();
      var subj = "Subject: " + ss.getRange('D33').getValues();
      var copy = ss.getRange('D34:D40').getValues();

      var body = newDoc.getBody();

      body.editAsText().appendText(header);
      body.editAsText().appendText("\n\n");
      body.editAsText().appendText(subj);
      body.editAsText().appendText("\n\n");
      body.editAsText().appendText(copy);
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you provide an image of your spreadsheet and an image of what you would like your document to look like.  And then your description may begin to make more sense.

Comment: Hi, tried recorded sample would this help https://www.loom.com/share/1e4596d9551042058da4dc71137db760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

> Cannot change the styles of the header and subject in the created document.

## Solution

You just need to add the **Bold** and **Font Size** properties of your text appended. YOu can find more information about how to work with these methods [here for the bold](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setboldstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-bold) and [here for the font size](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setfontsizestartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-size) Here is the piece of code for doing so with comments explaining the functionality:

```js
 function copyTest() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

      // create a new document and add student as editor
      var newDoc = DocumentApp.create("Copy: " + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName());
      var targetDoc = newDoc.getId();

      var header = ss.getRange('A32').getValues();
      // separated the parts that go in bold and big from the other parts to make it more clear.
      var subj = "Subject: ";
      var subjtitle = ss.getRange('B2').getValues();
      var copy = ss.getRange('D34:D40').getValues();

      var body = newDoc.getBody();

      body.editAsText().appendText(header);
      body.editAsText().appendText("\n\n");
      // Add these styles for headigs from the character 0 (corresponding to the beginning of the text to the
      // character 17 which is the last part of the Subject: . This will make those characters in between
      // bold and with that font size (25) and the rest will keep them as normal plain text.
      body.editAsText().appendText(subj).setBold(0,17,true).setFontSize(0, 17, 25);
      body.editAsText().appendText(subjtitle);
      body.editAsText().appendText("\n\n");
      body.editAsText().appendText(copy);
    }
```

Other way of achieving this is to use the [class paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph) taking advantage of the [paragraph headings](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph-heading) to set the default styles or to create custom styles such as your required **heading 4**.

The following piece of code is just an example of the implementaion of this:

```js
function copyTest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // create a new document and add student as editor
  var newDoc = DocumentApp.create("Copy: " + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName());
  var targetDoc = newDoc.getId();
  
  var headertext = ss.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var subj = "Subject: ";
  var subjtitle = ss.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var copy = ss.getRange('B3:B4').getValues();
  
  var body =  newDoc.getBody();
  
  var header = body.appendParagraph(headertext+'\n\n'+subj);
  header.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING4);
    
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Hi, the setBold applies to the header first. Also, how can I change the text to a heading4? and paste 'copy' as is even if it contains bold text within the text? Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer with more resources to achieve what you aim. Please check the links I have attached to the documentation to learn how to add text with different styles in google docs with the API

Comment: hi, thanks that works. but for the copy i am having this error "Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Body.appendParagraph. ",

Comment: That is because copy is a string of values procedent from B3 and B4. You need to convert that array into a string or get the values separately and add them. Try this maybe: ```var fieldB3 = ss.getRange('B3').getValue(); var fieldB4 = ss.getRange('B4').getValue();``` and then use in the ```appendParagraph(fieldB3+fieldB4);```

Comment: Also consider accepting my answer if it worked to let other users know that did work :D